# Only show tooltip once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<a href=""><img src="image.jpg" class="tooltiphover img-responsive" data-original-title="Search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" /></a>
```

But I only want the tooltip to be shown once throughout the entire site.  At the moment this code is in an include file that is included on every page of the site.  If a user hovers over this image on the home page for example then I don't want the tooltip to be displayed any more on any page of the site.

I guess I'd have to use some kind of cookie / session.  I'm not really sure where to start here.  I suppose I'm asking how I would set a php session when someone mouseovers the image which would show the tooltip and then on other pages if the session exists then not to include the tooltip code.

Something like this:

```
$( ".tooltiphover" ).mouseout(function() {
<?php $showntooltip = "Yes"; ?>
});

<?php
if ($showntooltip != "Yes") { ?>
<a href=""><img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href=""><img src="image.jpg" class="tooltiphover img-responsive" data-original-title="Search" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" /></a>
}
?>
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you make your code work here? So we can help you out, as just simple HTML line is not enough to help you.

Comment: Also, do you want it to never show ever again or just for that particular session?

Comment: Just attach an hover event to your img. Depending on your answer to @DanEtchy question you can use sessionStorage or localStorage. To not show it again.

Comment: Thanks, have added some code

Comment: You cant change variables in php with javascript, php is a server side language, js in comparision a browser/client side language. Your browser will never see which php functions are executed. The only way to communicate between both is through $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, or for better understanding: forms.

Comment: Offtopic: instead of `$showntooltip = "Yes";` use `$showntooltip = true;`,  and check it with `if (!$showntooltip) { ... }`. boolean values are nicer to handle

Answer (score 0):

this will be very simple with html5 storage.

here is the link for  [html5 storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

By using Session Storage with javascript, you can disable tooltip after first click during session of visitor..

by using Local Storage with javascript, you can disable tooltip after first click in every session of visitor.

Just go on examples on link and you will find very well documented examples. and html5 storages are the future. They are very tiny and neat...